# フェールオーバークラスタリングについて

Tags: windows-server

どうしてもフェールオーバークラスタリング機能を用いたファイルサーバーのクラスター化が実現できません。いや、もしかしたら実現できているのかも？個人では判断できない状態で、ネットや書籍では大抵がクラスター構築までの手順が書いているだけで、そこからどうする？の部分に触れている情報が一切なく感じており、お手上げ状態です。

OSはWindows Server 2019 SEです。特にネットワークの部分の設定がうまくいってない気がします。

2ノード構成のファイルサーバー用クラスタリングを組む手順を教えて頂きたいです。宜しくお願いいたします。

ちなみにすべて仮想環境でやっており、VirtualBoxを使用しています。

【検証環境】
OS : Windows Server 2019 SE
仮想化ツール : Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.8
マシン構成 : DC x 1, クラスター構成ノード x 2, iSCSIターゲットサーバー x 1
ネットワーク環境 : スマホテザリング

補足 : iSCSIターゲットサーバーには、クォーラム用、データ用として2台の固定サイズ共有可能ディスクを積んでいます。また、2台のクラスター構成ノードには内部ネットワーク用のアダプターを追加し、互いにpingが通る状態です。

この辺りまでの私の取ってきた手順の中にで、「こういう点は確認しました？」みたいな気になれれる点がございましたらガンガン突っ込んで頂きたく思います。

追記 : すいません。追記はこちらでしたね。失礼致しました。既に色々と下記に書いてしまったのですが、とりあえずそういうことなのです。

Comment: 今の聞き方だと手順をすべて答えるか、すべて確認しないといけないので、このサイトの使い方には合いません。何をもって「うまくいっていない」と判断したのか書いてください。

Comment: 自分なら「構成の検証ウィザード」で警告されている点を確認して、その解決方法を聞くかな？そもそもVirtualBoxでWSFCが組めるものなのか確認しましたか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。あまりにぶつしけな質問の仕方でした。改めます。VirtualBoxでWSFCが組めるのかどうかまでの裏取りは、できておりません…。現在私がいつも行き詰まるポイントとしましては、クラスター作成後、役割の構成からファイルサーバーを選択し、それが「実行中」の状態になってから「ファイル共有の追加」を行おうとすると、「ファイル共有の取得に失敗しました」というメッセージが出る点が１つあります。

Comment: 因みにそのケースで失敗になる場合は、各クラスター構成ノードにそれぞれ1つずつのネットワークしか設定していなかった場合に起きることで、失敗ケース2は、各クラスター構成ノードに内部ネットワークアダプターを追加し、IPアドレスを振り、クラスター構成ノードどうしでpingが飛ぶ状態まで持っていきながら、いざクラスターを作成しようとするとテストの段階でネットワークエラーが出て詰まるパターンがございます。

Comment: 質問に関わる内容は、コメント欄ではなく質問の本文に直接追記してください。

Comment: さらに不思議？に思うことは、そんなエラーだらげで「大丈夫？」っていう状況にありながら、片方のノードを停止したりするとちゃんとフェールオーバーが行われ、生きているノードの方にクラスターディスクも移動しているという点があります。